Projective roots of a polynomial

Let $K$ an algebraically closed field and $F \in K[x,y]$ an homogeneus polynomial of $n \in \Bbb{N}$ degree. There exists $a \in K \setminus \{0\}, r\in \Bbb{N}^+, \{m_k\}_{k=1}^r \subset \Bbb{N}^+$ and $\{[a_k:b_k]\}_{k=1}^r \subset K\Bbb{P}^1$ such that $$F(x,y) = a \cdot \prod_{k=1}^r (a_k y - b_k x )^{m_k}$$

I am trying to prove this excercise from my Algebraic curves book but I am getting too stuck. The reason is that I do not find theoretical results that can be applied to this.
I have an idea that it seems difficult to formalize: it consist on express somehow $F$ as a polynomial of one variable, something like do the inverse process to homogenization, and take the roots given by the Fundamental Theorem. I am very unsure of this, so any possible help or advice would be very appreciated.
EDIT
Since $F$ is homogeneus, there is $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^n \subset K$ such that: $$ F(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{n-k}y^k $$
Now, define $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k = F(1,z) \in K[z]$. WLOG we can suppose that $a_n \neq 0$ . Then, since $K$ is algebraically closed, there are $r \in \Bbb{N}^+, \{m_k\}_{k=1}^r \subset \Bbb{N}^+$ and $\{\rho_k\}_{k=1}^r \subset K$ such that: $$f(z) = a_n \prod_{k=1}^r(z-\rho_k)^{m_k}$$
Then we have that $\sum_{k=1}^r m_k = n$ and $$F(x,y) = x^n f(y/x) = x^n a_n \prod_{k=1}^r \left( \frac{y}{x} - \rho_k \right)^{m_k} = \frac{x^n a_n}{x^{\sum_{k=1}^r m_k}} \prod_{k=1}^r (y - \rho_k x)^{m_k} = a_n \prod_{k=1}^r (y - \rho_k x)^{m_k}$$
and we have finished by taking $[a_k: b_k] = [1 : \rho_k]$ . Is this fine? I am unsure of my WLOG assumption but it seems well to me.

Your idea is what I would have done as well. Search for "homogenization" and "dehomogenization". But without the roots.

Why do you call this "projective roots", actually? We have a sum here?

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks for your help! What I mean by projective roots is that the statement put them on the projective line over $K$
